# Как динамически обновлять Bean в @Configuration классе

Tags: java, spring

```
@Configuration
public class TestScheduleConfig {

@Autowired
private TestScheduleRepo testScheduleRepo;

@RefreshScope
@Bean
public String getCronValue() throws Throwable {

    Optional optional = testScheduleRepo.findById(1);
    TestScheduleEntity entity = (TestScheduleEntity) optional.orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Запись не найдена"));
    String result = entity.getSecond() + " " +
            entity.getMinute() + " " +
            entity.getHour() + " " +
            entity.getMonthDay() + " " +
            entity.getMonth() + " " +
            entity.getWeekDay()
            ;

    return result;
}
```

}

```
@Service
public class TestScheduleMethod {

    @Scheduled(cron="#{@getCronValue}")
    public void printToConsole() {
        System.out.println("SCHEDULE SUCCESS!!!");
    }
}
```

Есть задача:
Настроить расписание @Scheduled получая данные из БД.

У меня получилось настроить это как в коде выше (простой пример). Но если данные в БД изменятся, применить их можно только перезапустив приложение. Нашел предпологаемое решение: использовать аннотацию @RefreshScope, как в коде (@EnableConfigServer тоже стоит за кадром). Однако, на просторах интернета нашел, что эта аннотация не работает для @Configuration классов и методов, отмеченных аннотацией @Scheduled.

Это боль! Нужно сделать красиво и лаконично - безо всяких XML. Возможно ли это используя мой код? Если нет, то как выйти из данной ситуации и решить поставленную задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Не получится лаконично описать динамичное расписание через аннотацию. Чтобы подобное реализовать, нужно самому описать запуск и остановку задач. Так же необходимо самому следить за изменениями в БД и переинициализировать задачу при изменении расписания. Например, как [описано тут](http://mbcoder.com/dynamic-task-scheduling-with-spring/)